# field data is breaking in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, words

In my crystal report I have a formula which counts the number of words.  The problem I am facing is that every time I preview the report, some words get cut automatically.  I tried using the `can grow` property with 2 lines, in addition to line spacing of 1.8, to no avail.

An example line of data would be:

```
Twenty five thousand two hundred and thirty only
```

Instead, the report outputs something like:

```
Twenty five thousand two hundred an
d thirty only
```

How can I fix this?  Thanks!

Comment: can grow will increase the length vertically not horizontally. Increase the width to accomodate the full text

Comment: thanks siva but the problem is there is no deinite size which i know earlier sometimes it is coming as 20 char and sometime 50.